# tomcat proxy - How to set up a proxy location for some virtual host apache 2

Tags: apache, http, tomcat

ive my httpd.conf generic option as :

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/

</Location>
```

I would like to configure virtualhost which include

Like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName  www.localhost        
        ServerAlias locathost
        DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\tomcat"
   <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/

</Location>

<VirtualHost *:80>
```

in the same time if i called other virtaul host it should serv through port 80 not 8080

like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName  www.localhost2nd
        ServerAlias locathost2nd
        DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\phpapp"

<VirtualHost *:80>
```

so what do i miss in my configuration its never works